# vim split if the buffer not empty

Tags: vim

I try create a map for open ~/.vimrc, but open the ~/.vimrc only when the buffer is empty, else split and open.
I try this

```
fun! BufferIsEmpty() "{{{                                                                
    if line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == ''                                                
        return 1                                                                         
    else                                                                                 
        return 0                                                                         
    endif                                                                                
endf "}}}                                                                                
fun! NotEmptySplit() "{{{                                                                
    if !BufferIsEmpty()                                                                  
        sp                                                                               
    endif                                                                                
    return                                                                               
endf                                                                                     
command! -nargs=0 NotEmptySplit call NotEmptySplit()  
nnoremap <silent><leader>ve :NotEmptySplit <bar> ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

but I get this error

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

Comment: I'd also check if the name of the current buffer is empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To take kev's excellent answer a bit further:

How about pulling out a generic 'open file in split if buffer not empty' function.

```
fu! OpenInSplitIfBufferDirty(file)
    if line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == ''
        exec 'e' a:file
    else
        exec 'sp' a:file
    endif
endfu

nnoremap <silent> <leader>ve :call OpenInSplitIfBufferDirty($MYVIMRC)<cr>
command -nargs=1 -complete=file -bar CleverOpen :call OpenInSplitIfBufferDirty(<q-args>)
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding `-bar` option will fix the `E488` error.

```
command! -bar -nargs=0 NotEmptySplit call NotEmptySplit()
nnoremap <silent><leader>ve :NotEmptySplit <BAR> ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

But it will raise another `E488` error from `<BAR> ~/.vimrc<CR>`.

---

I'm trying to refactor your code:

```
fun! OpenVimrc()
    if line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == ''
        e $MYVIMRC
    else
        sp $MYVIMRC
    endif
endf

nnoremap <silent><leader>ve :call OpenVimrc()<CR>
```

---

These is a variable called `b:changedtick` to track changing counter.