# How to add some lines to the current Vim buffer by using a VimL script?

Tags: vim

I am confused about doing a really simple task. I need to add lines to the current buffer with a VimL script.

As it is known, there are two functions for this: `append()` and `setline()`. Both of them work approximately similarly — the first argument is the number of the line to perform insertion at (after or before, respectively), the second one defines the line(s) to add.

But the problem is that I cannot determine the number properly without inventing weird tricks. The only standard method I have found is to ask the `line('$')` function. So, to add a line to the end of the current buffer it can be `append(line('$'), ['example'])` or `setline(line('$')+1, 'example')`. But this approach gives unpredictable results depending on the content of the current buffer.

Let’s consider `append(line('$'), ['example'])` first. If the buffer is not empty, I get what I expect:

```
first existing line
example
```

But if the buffer is empty, I will get the first line blank:

```
example
```

Now, let’s take a look at `setline(line('$')+1, 'example')`. It works conversely. If the buffer is empty, everything is fine:

```
example
```

But if the buffer is not empty, trying to add “example” after the last line, I get a mess of text lines:

```
first existing line
example
second existing line
```

Well, I could test the last line whether it is blank or not. But what if the last line is empty due to the content?

So, here are my questions. Should my code analyze the content of the current buffer to decide which of the functions it must choose, considering whether the existing last line is empty because this is how the function `line('$')` works or it empty due to the desired content? Or should I use another approach that I have missed?

Perhaps, I should utilize something like:

```
write! buffer.tmp
exe '! printf '.join(g:my_lines_to_add, "\n")."\n >>buffer.tmp"
edit! buffer.tmp
rm -f buffer.tmp
```

Is there a trivial standard way to solve this trivial task? My text may sound brute, but I love Vim and count myself as its experienced user. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all, especially to `Olivia` and `romainl`!

Files may or may not have zero lines, but a Vim buffer always has at least one line, even it is empty actually. So, it is impossible to determine the line number the new content is adding after without understanding the existing content of the buffer.

We can use two main approaches:

- not to analyze the content and not to worry about a redundant blank line;
- to analyze the content to avoid an unwanted blank line;

In the first case, we must always use `append(line('$'), ...)`, not as I said `append(line('$')-1, ...)` in my answer to `Olivia`. I was wrong because if the content of the buffer had an empty line at the end (for example, to separate the paragraphs),  using `line('$')-1` would lead to a loss of the text structure. But using `append(line('$'), ...`  leads to the first line is always blank.

The second approach is more interesting as it implies content analysis. It is not so hard as it can be thought. `romainl` suggests using the `wordcount()` function, `Olivia` advises testing the line and column numbers.

I did not profile the code. But, I am sure, on huge texts, Olivia’s suggestion is much more effective because knowing the number of lines and counting the bytes in the text are jobs of significantly different complexity.

So, the solution is turning out the following. (The code has not been tested yet, this is a concept).

```
function Append(lines)
    " Add the given lines to the end of the current buffer.
    "
    " Arguments:
    "     ‛lines’
    "        a list of text lines to add to the buffer.
    "
    let index = (line('$') == 1) && (col('$') == 1) ? 1 : line('$') + 1
    call setline(index, a:lines)
endfunction
```

Thanks for all one more time! The question is closed.

Comment: `line('$') == 1 && col('$') == 1` is indeed much faster but `wordcount().bytes` is in the single digit milliseconds already so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: Yes, it’s super-fast too. I think that is because `wordcount().bytes` retrieves the information directly from the file system instead of recounting the bytes by itself. Thus, your solution works fine too.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few conflicting questions in here.

As you've already noticed, you use `append()` (or, to borrow a phrase [from this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12450), "`appendline()`") or `setline()`. Both of these take a line number and a string or an array, which is then handled appropriately by the function.

> the first argument is the number of the line to perform insertion at (after or before, respectively).

Strictly speaking, no. Go to any file, and go to the first line. Run `:echo line('.')`. It'll return 1. This is the part I hate most about Vim/Vimscript: `line()` and `getline()` are 1-indexed. But if you use the array returned by `getline()`, you get a 0-indexed array. Consequently:

`append()` adds a number of lines *after* the first argument. It doesn't affect the line at `idx`. `setline()` changes the line *at* `idx` and `len(text)` out. This means that the functions perform their operation, respectively, after or at, not before.

> Should my code analyze the content of the current buffer to decide which of the functions it must choose, considering whether the existing last line is empty because this is how the function line('$') works or it empty due to the desired content?

I can't answer this with a definite yes or no, because it's a matter of what you want to do. There's different approaches based on what end result you're looking for, and how much scripting you're fine with.

You may some times need to do comparisons, but you often don't need to make it that complicated. In your particular case, as I'll demonstrate in a bit, you can get away with checking the line count, and then making sure the only line isn't empty. It's a bit messy to write, but it does the trick. You can also do various comparisons.

Consider `append(line('$') - 1, ["example"])`: in an empty buffer, this gives

```
example
```

... and note the blank line at the end of the file. Line 1 is still preserved, because append *doesn't overwrite lines*. Sadly, the blank line is considered a line, so there's no particularly easy way to do it with built-in functions, because there aren't any that do this<sup>AFAIK</sup>.

So, let's look at your options:

### Single-line `setline()`

The shortest single-line option is:

```
call setline(1, add(line('$') == 1 && col('$') == 1 ? [] : getline(0, '$'), 'example'))
```

There's a lot going on here, so let's break it down:

```
setline(                            We use setline(), because it can override existing lines.
        1,                          Start at line 1. 
        add(                        add() appends to an array.
                                    Then we have a condition using ternary.
            line('$') == 1          If the last line is line 1...
            && col('$') == 1        and the last column is 1...
            ? []                    then we use an empty array.
            : getline(0, '$'),      Otherwise, we get the contents of the buffer
            'example')              and add 'example' to the array
        )
```

Note that you need to use `extend()` if you want to add several items, NOT insert! See `:h insert()` and `:h extend()`.

### Single-line `append()`

If you're fine with a blank line at the end of the file for empty files, you can also use append:

```
call append(line('$') == 1 && col('$') == 1 ? 0 : line('$'), ["example"])
```

Again, `append()` CANNOT override existing lines, so you're stuck with a blank line somewhere. Which leads us to...

### If approach

This can be reduced into a single statement, which I'll include for copy-pasta purposes, but this is *much* better used if you're writing a script, and not just using it as a command:

```
if line('$') == 1 && col('$') == 1 | call setline(1, 'example') | else | call append(line('$'), "example") | endif
```

Or, in its expanded, script-friendly form:

```
if line('$') == 1 && col('$') == 1
    call setline(1, 'example')
else
    call append(line('$'), "example")
endif
```

... which is indirectly what you asked about.

In some ways, this is an easier to read variant of the first option, at least for script use. If you have a script, you can actually get away with just `append`.

### A note on hacks

By using the `append` approach, you can move the condition that determines the line into a variable, and use that in combination with `normal! "Gdd"` (`G`oto last line, `dd`elete line) to get rid of the blank line. You can use an equivalent approach if you detect an empty file.

### TL;DR:

> But the problem is that I cannot determine the number properly without inventing weird tricks.

It's not particularly weird with this particular use-case, at least when you know exactly what it means. It's definitely a hack none the less, but not much to do about that in this particular case.

> Should my code analyze the content of the current buffer to decide which of the functions it must choose,

in this case, `line('$') == 1 && col('$') == 1` is enough. (AFAIK, [we don't have a better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11060984/16781553), but this does avoid string operations).

> considering whether the existing last line is empty because this is how the function line('$') works

`line('$')` is a victim here. Blank lines are still considered lines, and that holds for every other function as well. Consequently, `append()` doesn't want to override it. Whether the line is blank or not, `line('$') == 1` if there's only one line in the buffer. Annoyingly enough, `line('.') == 1`, but `line('^') == 0`. I can't explain that one, but this happens in single-line buffers regardless of the contents of said line.

> or it empty due to the desired content?

Now mildly out of context thanks to creative quoting, but the blank line that appears from a few of these combinations is an unavoidable fact based on how the functions work. You need a varying index to deal with these cases, but it really depends on what you want to do in the first place. There may be a better and/or shorter alternative, but that requires me to make assumptions about your code.

> Or should I use another approach that I have missed?

There are a few alternatives in this answer already, that can be expanded if necessary. There's a lot of ways to Rome with this particular question, so there probably is. I've probably missed a few approaches as well though, for what little that's worth.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It turns out that there is no painless way to add some lines at the end of the buffer without keeping the empty line. Your examples of code prove it. Speaking in the shell language, `cat ${some_lines} >>${existing_buffer)` is not possible in VimL. In the common case, I cannot get rid of the redundant empty line — it will be either at the beginning or at the end of the buffer. It seems the simplest way is to choose the lesser of evils and leave blank lines at the end. So, `append(line('$')-1, ...)` becomes the winner.

Answer (score 1):

You are making things sound harder than they are.

You can check if the current buffer is empty with:

```
wordcount().bytes == 0
```

and you can forget about `append()` as `setline()` does the job perfectly *as long as you give it the right line*:

```
if wordcount().bytes == 0
    " buffer is empty so our target is the last line itself
    call setline('$', ['foo', 'bar'])
else
    " buffer is not empty so our target is the line after the last line:
    call setline(line('$') + 1, ['foo', 'bar'])
endif
```

From there, you can fine tune the way you handle the "last line is blank or empty" scenario by adding more checks to the second branch of the conditional…

- if a given line is empty:

  ```
  getline(<line spec>) =~ '^$'
  ```
- if a given line is non-empty and made only of whitespace:

  ```
  getline(<line spec>) !~ '^$' && getline(<line spec>) !~ '\S'
  ```
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a fancy one-liner?

```
let foo =<< END
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
END

:call execute(["$append"] + foo)
```